# Virtual hosts (on CentOS) show same content

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have added two different virtual hosts on Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /home/domain1/www

ServerName domain1.kz

ServerAlias www.domain1.kz

</VirtualHost *:80>

<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /home/domain2/www

ServerName domain2.kz

ServerAlias domain2.kz

</VirtualHost *:80>
```

When I visit domain2.kz, it shows the content of first virtual host, even if their DocumentRoot are different? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Well, for a start, your closing tags aren't, so you might want to fix those up and try again.  They should look like `</VirtualHost>`, without the listen spec.